# Is it possible to change an internship visa to a work visa in Germany without leaving the country?

Tags: working-visas, internship

I'm from India and I'm currently doing an internship in Germany. The organization that gave me the internship also offered me a job now. Is it possible for me to change the status of my visa from an internship visa to a work visa from Germany itself? Or do I need to go back to India to do the same?

Comment: I am afraid nobody could answer you at the time, but maybe you could come back and provide an answer on how you solved this, in order to help future users? That would be great.

Comment: was your "internship visa" type-C or type-D visa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just want to provide some closure to this thread. It is actually possible to convert an internship visa to a job visa from within Germany. Just take an appointment at your city's Auslanderbehorde (Foreigners office). They will give you a list of documents like your work contract, current residence permit, etc. And then they will give you a new residence permit after the processing is complete.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and reporting!